# What kind of prior knowledge/Background one needs to work with Graphs using MM?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

Is there any freely available university course from which I can learn how to think about graphs and their properties using MM functions and related packages such as i Graph/M,i Graph and Combinatorica .

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.
Many thanks.

PS:

1) Mathematica/WL is my first programming language  and just started to learn  it seriously  like 2- months for now.

2) I do also use french,German and Italian. So any resources in these languages are welcome as well.

Comment: This is probably too broad a question for this Q&A format. However, the *Mathematica* help in itself can already be a great resource, and provides lots of examples to play around with. As for the question title, that is not really perfectly congruent to the question posed in the text, which is more about references rather than prior knowledge...

Comment: @ Yves Klett . Thank you.